# How to solve the flowchart question dealing with values in an array?

Tags: induction

[image]

I am not able to comprehend the meaning in the general sense. I have tried all the online resources and books available to understand what this symbols mean and have quite naturally arrived at this. However when they are connected I am not able to understand how the values will be replaced by one another. A guidance about the same will be most certainly welcome. A schematic with how the values change with ever iteration will be most certainly welcome.

Comment: Are you having trouble understanding how to follow the flowchart, or the instructions in each step, or something about what the boxes represent?

Comment: Instructions in each step.... Unable to overwrite the values..Btw I like your name @ConMan

Comment: Why are you unable? Write the boxes down on paper, then cross them out and write the new values as you go? Or if you want to see how things progress, use a spreadsheet where each row contains the values of the boxes after each step in the flowchart.

Comment: @ConMan Please assit me with the first 2-3 steps. I am unable to make any progress in the first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a step-through of what happens in the first few steps of the first flowchart.

| Bubble | Action | Box 1 | Box 2 | Box 3 | Box 4 | Box 5 | Box 6 | Box 7 | Box 8 | Box 9 | Box 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Start | Go to A | 13 | 20 | 7 | 12 | 10 | 2 | 5 | 1 | 0 | 18 |
| A | Box 4 - Box 1 = 12 - 13 = -1 => Box 10, go to B | 13 | 20 | 7 | 12 | 10 | 2 | 5 | 1 | 0 | -1 |
| B | Box 10 < -1 is TRUE, go to C | 13 | 20 | 7 | 12 | 10 | 2 | 5 | 1 | 0 | -1 |
| C | Box 9 + Box 5 = 0 + 10 = 10 => Box 2, go to D | 13 | 10 | 7 | 12 | 10 | 2 | 5 | 1 | 0 | -1 |
| D | Box 2 > Box 7 is TRUE, go to E | 13 | 10 | 7 | 12 | 10 | 2 | 5 | 1 | 0 | -1 |

Can you see what's happening here? What happens in the next step? And per the question, what happens if the instruction on step C is to put the result in Box 3?